# numpy.ndarray has no columns

Tags: python, openml

this is my python code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# Fetching the dataset
dataset = fetch_openml(data_id=1046)

# Creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset.data, columns=dataset.feature_names)

# Adding the target variable to the dataframe
df['target'] = dataset.target

# Checking for missing values
print(df.isnull().sum())

# Imputing missing values using mean imputation for numeric features and most frequent imputation for nominal features

numeric_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns
nominal_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns

imputer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'), numeric_features),
        ('cat', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'), nominal_features)
    ])

df_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(df)

# Encoding nominal features
encoder = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('cat', OneHotEncoder(), nominal_features)
    ], remainder='passthrough')

X = encoder.fit_transform(df_imputed)
y = df_imputed['target']

# Scaling the features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

and I get this error:

Exception has occurred: ValueError
Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\icefo\Desktop\1 (2).py", line 39, in 
X = encoder.fit_transform(df_imputed)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames

I read couple of other questions but I cannot find my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the mentioned error on this line below :

```
X = encoder.fit_transform(df_imputed)
```

because you're passing an empty ndarray to the method fit_transform.

```
print(df_imputed)
>> []
```